# Caching MathJax output in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, rotation, mathjax

I am embedding MathJax in a UIWebView in my app which handle's user content. It is working really well. However, every time the user rotates the app, the UIWebView is reloaded which causes the MathJax to have to be processed again. Is there a way to cache the MathJax output, so that when the user rotates the app and then rotates back, it does not need to be re-calculated and re-rendered?

Comment: Just a thought, couldn't you serialise it to a string and reload it on rotate?

Comment: How would I do that? I.e. when you say "serialize it to a string" - serialize what exactly? The Mathjax output? If so, where would I be able to access it?

Comment: sorry I assumed you had a reference to the output jax, I haven't actually used MathJax myself.

Comment: There's currently no MathJax-internal way of doing so. The problem is that a change in viewport can change the layout enough to require a re-render (e.g. linebreaking will be different). Storing MathJax output in local storage might work, especially if you're using SVG output.